# java recursion and class object with factorial

Tags: java, recursion

i was assigned a problem to write a program using recursion, which is working properly, my only question is that it was specified to create a class object to do the factorial calculation instead of method...am I doing this right?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment2A {

public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //sets up scanner
    boolean correct = true;             //sets up boolean operation
    while(true){
    try{                                //try catch operation
        System.out.println("Welcome to the factorial function");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number or press 0 to exit");
        long startTime =System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Start Time: "+startTime+" nanoseconds."); //display the start time

        int n = scan.nextInt();             //scans the input
        int factorial= fact(n);             
        System.out.println("The Factorial of the number entered is: " + factorial);

        long taskTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+" nanoseconds.\n\n");

    }catch(Exception e){                //checks if the input is a string or character
        System.out.println("That is not a number!");    //displays that the input is invalid
        long startTime =System.nanoTime();
        long taskTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+" nanoseconds.");
        System.exit(0);         //exits the program
        }
    }
}

static int fact(int n){
int output;                 //sets the output as int
long startTime = System.nanoTime();     //gets the start time of the cpu
long taskTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;    //gets the task time
if (n==0){                      //if the input is 0, system exits
    System.out.println("Exiting Program");      
    System.out.println("Task Time: "+taskTime+ " nanoseconds."); //displays cpu time
    System.exit(0);
}
else if(n==1){
    return 1;           //if input is 1, the factorial of 1 is 1
}
output = fact(n-1)*n;   //recursive method for factorial
  return output;
 }
}
```